# Recovering Ubuntu setup without reinstalling

Tags: grub2, data-recovery

I believe that I broke my Ubuntu partition by removing python3.8. Now the GRUB option has changed from Ubuntu to Debian and I can only get into a shell via recovery mode. In this state it doesn't look like my network card is being recognized (`ip link` only shows loopback and multicast, and if I try to use `apt` to install anything it just tells me it can't get to any of the repos.

Is there a reasonable way to recover from this state without having to reinstall the OS?

Comment: Nope, reinstall is going to be the fastest way.  Attempting to boot into the livecd and reinstall all the Python components and the entire dependency tree is going to be its own nightmare.  LONG STORY SHORT, **do not remove Python from your system unless you REALLY know what you're doing**.  And even then, you probably shouldn't remove Python that was installed by default.

Comment: That's about what I thought - thanks for the quick response!